# Facebook Pages audience data

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

When creating an advertisement for a fan page, I can choose its target audience, by age, sex, location, interest lists and other criteria.

On my fan page's analytics data, I can see my current audience age, location and  sex.

Is there a way of knowing what my current audience likes in order to better target my ads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Facebook Graph Search. You should be able to get what you are looking for.

Comment: Awesome idea. Hadn't ocurred to me. Thanks a lot! Luckily I have Graph Search enabled; searching for "Pages liked by people who like <MYPAGENAME>" did the trick.